# Prometheus Summaries Do Not Refresh Their Values

Tags: ruby, prometheus, fluentd

I have a fluentd running with the prometheus [plugin](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-prometheus).

It collects logs, parses them, extracts latencies and displays them on `/metrics` endpoint as advertised + sends the original logs to my aggregation system.

However, I've noticed that some latencies don't refresh their values:

```
web_latencies_summary{response_code="408",quantile="0.5"} 60.0
web_latencies_summary{response_code="408",quantile="0.9"} 60.496
web_latencies_summary{response_code="408",quantile="0.99"} 60.496
web_latencies_summary_sum{response_code="408"} 421.597
web_latencies_summary_count{response_code="408"} 7
```

I check the logs and I haven't had any 408's for over 24hrs, but the `/metrics` endpoint still displays the values above. This obviously throws my metrics off by a lot.

What could be going wrong? I believe most of the prometheus clients replace the value with NaN when there was nothing for a while. It does not happen in this case.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Isn't there an option to have a window (time or number of data point) for the summary ?

Comment: This seems to be a limitation of prometheus client ruby implementation. See [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/client_ruby/issues/12)